# Clone derived class from base class method

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have an abstract base class `Base` which has some common properties, and many derived ones which implement different logic but rarely have additional fields.

```
public abstract Base
{
    protected int field1;
    protected int field2;
    ....

    protected Base() { ... }
}
```

Sometimes I need to clone the derived class. So my guess was, just make a virtual `Clone` method in my base class and only override it in derived classes that have additional fields, but of course my `Base` class wouldn't be abstract anymore (which isn't a problem since it only has a `protected` constructor).

```
public Base
{
    protected int field1;
    protected int field2;
    ....

    protected Base() { ... }

    public virtual Base Clone() { return new Base(); }
}

public A : Base { }
public B : Base { }
```

1. The thing is, since I can't know the type of the derived class in my Base one, wouldn't this lead to have a `Base` class instance even if I call it on the derived ones ? (`a.Clone();`) (actually after a test this is what is happening but perhaps my test wasn't well designed that's why I have a doubt about it)
2. Is there a good way (pattern) to implement a base `Clone` method that would work as I expect it or do I have to write the same code in every derived class (I'd really like to avoid that...)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why not just make the `Clone` method abstract so it has to be implemented by the derived classes?

Comment: @Bob. that's what I've done originally, but it lead me to write duplicate code. Nearly everything could be done in the base clone method, that's why

Comment: Why not use `this.MemberwiseClone()` ?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel because I do some modifications in the fields during the cloning process, it's not exactly a clone, but close to is. But this could be an option anyway since I call that cloning method only in 1 place, it would just have been better to implement that logic in the base class

Comment: @ppetrov That makes sense, check my ansewer, and Alexander Simonov also has good answer as well

Comment: Indeed both are good answers, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just override the `Clone` and have another method to `CreateInstance`  then do your stuff.

This way you could have only `Base` class avoiding generics.

```
public Base
{
    protected int field1;
    protected int field2;
    ....

    protected Base() { ... }

    public virtual Base Clone() 
    { 
        var bc = CreateInstanceForClone();
        bc.field1 = 1;
        bc.field2 = 2;
        return bc;
    }

    protected virtual Base CreateInstanceForClone()
    {
        return new Base(); 
    }
}


public A : Base 
{     
    protected int fieldInA;
    public override Base Clone() 
    { 
        var a = (A)base.Clone();
        a.fieldInA =5;
        return a;
    }

    protected override Base CreateInstanceForClone()
    {
        return new A(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Close, but no cigar. When cloning an A, how are field1 and field2 copied over?

Comment: @KrisVandermotten That's typo. Is that ok now?

Comment: I did something similar but defined `Clone()` once only in the base class, and all it does is call a virtual `CloneImpl()`. The base class's `CloneImpl()` implementation only performs a `MemberwiseCopy()` which constructs a copy of whatever type is actually calling.  All derived `CloneImpl()`s (in a multi-tier inheritance hierarchy) first call `base.CloneImpl()` to perform all deep copying of all base class members, and then deal with their own members needing deep copy semantics.

Answer (score 19):

You can add a copy constructor to your base class:

```
public abstract Base
{
    protected int field1;
    protected int field2;

    protected Base() { ... }

    protected Base(Base copyThis) : this()
    { 
        this.field1 = copyThis.field1;
        this.field2 = copyThis.field2;
    }

    public abstract Base Clone();
}

public Child1 : Base
{
    protected int field3;

    public Child1 () : base() { ... }

    protected Child1 (Child1  copyThis) : base(copyThis)
    {
        this.field3 = copyThis.field3;
    }

    public override Base Clone() { return new Child1(this); }
}

public Child2 : Base
{
    public Child2 () : base() { ... }

    protected Child (Child  copyThis) : base(copyThis)
    {  }

    public override Base Clone() { return new Child2(this); }
}

public Child3 : Base
{
    protected int field4;

    public Child3 () : base() { ... }

    protected Child3 (Child3  copyThis) : base(copyThis)
    {
        this.field4 = copyThis.field4;
    }

    public override Base Clone()
    {
        var result = new Child1(this);
        result.field1 = result.field2 - result.field1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's a good solution, I'd mark both of the answers as accepted if I could, but I'll have to go with the other one since it makes more sense in my context not to have a copy constructor.

Comment: I think this is a nice method. +1 Good job

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I also think this is a nice method (I upvoted), but I don't really copy all the fields in my clone method, I do some more things, that's why it makes more sens to have a separate method for this rather than a copy constructor, had to make a choice

Comment: @ppetrov, nothing stops you from doing other stuff in `Clone()` method. See `Child3` class, I've updated my answer.

Comment: @AlexanderSimonov indeed, but the thing is I don't need a copy, I need a slightly modified copy, that's why I prefer having a method which name is explicit about it, and a copy constructor can't have a different name from the class. It's not a technical issue, just a naming one

Comment: this will not work if you have reference types fields in your base class?

Comment: @tytyryty, it will work almost the same way for value type and for reference type fields. The only difference is that value type fields are copied by value and reference type fields are copied by reference value. It is called a shallow copy.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
public class Base<T> where T: Base<T>, new()
{
    public virtual T Clone() 
    { 
        T copy = new T();
        copy.Id = this.Id;
        return copy;
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class A : Base<A>
{
    public override A Clone()
    {
        A copy = base.Clone();
        copy.Name = this.Name;
        return copy;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

private void Test()
{
    A a = new A();
    A aCopy = a.Clone();
}
```

But i doubt that it will bring something useful. I'll create another example..

Comment: +1 It's close to it, but the thing is I'd really like to avoid the generic parameter when dealing with the base class. I mostly only use the base class in my code

Comment: @ppetrov, you can implement it without generic base class. [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19120065/1166450).

Comment: You _could_ indeed implement it like this, but read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx

Comment: When I want to write class B that inherited from class A, how will it look like?

Answer (score 3):

I did something similar as Alexander Simonov, but perhaps simpler. The idea is (as I said in a comment) to have just *one* `Clone()` in the base class and leave all the work to a virtual `CloneImpl()` which each class defines as needed, relying on the `CloneImpl()`s of the base classes.

Creation of the proper type is left to C#'s `MemberwiseClone()` which will do whatever it takes for the object that's calling. This also obviates the need for a default constructor in any of the classes (none is ever called).

```
using System;

namespace CloneImplDemo
{
    // dummy data class
    class DeepDataT : ICloneable 
    {
        public int i;
        public object Clone() { return MemberwiseClone(); } 
    }

    class Base: ICloneable
    {
        protected virtual Base CloneImpl()
        { 
            // Neat: Creates the type of whatever object is calling. 
            // Also obviates the need for default constructors
            // (Neither Derived1T nor Derived2T have one.)
            return (Base)MemberwiseClone();
        }

        public object Clone() 
        {
            // Calls whatever CloneImpl the  
            // actual calling type implements.
            return CloneImpl();
        }
    }

    // Note: No Clone() re-implementation
    class Derived1T : Base
    {
        public Derived1T(int i) { der1Data.i = i; }
        public DeepDataT der1Data = new DeepDataT();
        protected override Base CloneImpl()
        {
            Derived1T cloned = (Derived1T)base.CloneImpl();
            cloned.der1Data = (DeepDataT)der1Data.Clone();
            return cloned;
        }
    }

    // Note: No Clone() re-implementation.
    class Derived2T : Derived1T
    {
        public Derived2T(int i1, int i2) : base(i1)
        {
            der2Data.i = i2;
        }
        public string txt = string.Empty; // copied by MemberwiseClone()
        public DeepDataT der2Data = new DeepDataT();
        protected override Base CloneImpl()
        {
            Derived2T cloned = (Derived2T)base.CloneImpl();
            // base members have been taken care of in the base impl.
            // we only add our own stuff.
            cloned.der2Data = (DeepDataT)der2Data.Clone();
            return cloned;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var obj1 = new Derived2T(1,2);
            obj1.txt = "this is obj1";

            var obj2 = (Derived2T)obj1.Clone();
            obj2.der1Data.i++;
            obj2.der2Data.i++; // changes value.
            obj2.txt = "this is a deep copy"; // replaces reference.

            // the values for i should differ because 
            // we performed a deep copy of the DeepDataT members.
            Console.WriteLine("obj1 txt, i1, i2: " + obj1.txt + ", " + obj1.der1Data.i + ", " + obj1.der2Data.i);
            Console.WriteLine("obj2 txt, i1, i2: " + obj2.txt + ", " + obj2.der1Data.i + ", " + obj2.der2Data.i);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
obj1 txt, i1, i2: this is obj1, 1, 2
obj2 txt, i1, i2: this is a deep copy, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I got another idea using the Activator class:

```
public class Base
{
    public virtual object Clone()
    {
        Base copy = (Base)Activator.CreateInstance(this.GetType());
        copy.Id = this.Id;
        return copy;
    }


    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class A : Base
{
    public override object Clone()
    {
        A copy = (A)base.Clone();
        copy.Name = this.Name;
        return copy;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

A a = new A();
A aCopy = (A)a.Clone();
```

**But i would go for the Alexander Simonov answer.**

Comment: It would work, if all derived classes have a public parameterless constructor. But it certainly is not the most efficient implementation.

Comment: Actually in my particular context this would work, since the constructors of every derived classes have the same signature, but I prefer to avoid that kind of methods when I can, not a big fan of Activator and refletcion

Answer (score 0):

If performance is not important for your case, you can simplify your code by creating just one general clone method which can clone whatever to whatever if properties are same:

```
Base base = new Base(){...};
Derived derived = XmlClone.CloneToDerived<Base, Derived>(base);


public static class XmlClone
{
    public static D CloneToDerived<T, D>(T pattern)
        where T : class
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms))
            {
                Type typePattern = typeof(T);
                Type typeTarget = typeof(D);

                XmlSerializer xmlSerializerIn = new XmlSerializer(typePattern);
                xmlSerializerIn.Serialize(writer, pattern);
                ms.Position = 0;
                XmlSerializer xmlSerializerOut = new XmlSerializer(typeTarget, new XmlRootAttribute(typePattern.Name));
                D copy = (D)xmlSerializerOut.Deserialize(ms);                    
                return copy;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this question while trying to solve this exact problem, had some fun with LINQPad while at it.
Proof of concept:

```
void Main()
{
    Person p = new Person() { Name = "Person Name", Dates = new List<System.DateTime>() { DateTime.Now } };

    new Manager()
    {
        Subordinates = 5
    }.Apply(p).Dump();
}

public static class Ext
{
    public static TResult Apply<TResult, TSource>(this TResult result, TSource source) where TResult: TSource
    {
        var props = typeof(TSource).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (var p in props)
        {
            p.SetValue(result, p.GetValue(source));
        }

        return result;
    }
}

class Person 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<DateTime> Dates { get; set; }
}

class Manager : Person
{
    public int Subordinates { get; set; }
}
```