# instance accesses property value of other instances

Tags: c#, properties, instance

My purpose is getting the data from user interface and saving it as a configuration. The program allows to config multiple person so i am trying to save each person settings. I have realized something. Whenever i change the data from one instance, the other instances values change.

```
public class Person()
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public void Change()
    {
        Name = "F";
    }
}
```

This is my person class

This is my main

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Person person = new Person();
    Person person2 = new Person();
    Person current = new Person();

    person.Name = "John";
    person2.Name = "Doe";
    current.Name = "Robert";

    person = current;
    person2 = current;
    current.Change()
}
```

after current.Change() the person 1 and person 2 name changes to "F". This behavious got me confused because i would expect this result on

```
    person = current;
    person2 = current;
    current.Change()
    person = current;
    person2 = current;
```

What i want is to use current on the interface. Get the datas and save them to person instances. The problem is, when i change current, all other instance properties change to same and i lose my config settings.

How can i achieve my purpose? Any ideas?

Thank you so much! Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Person` is a reference type, when you do `person2 = current;` you are in fact just pointing the `person2` reference to the `current` object in memory, which is also pointed to by `person`.

Thus, any changes made via one reference will change the same physical object in memory as any changes made via the other reference.

What you need to do is to make an actual copy of the object.

One common way to do this is to write a ["Copy constructor"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-write-a-copy-constructor) to make a copy. You can also write a `Copy()` method that uses the copy constructor for implementation, but that isn't really necessary unless you have an inheritance hierarchy.

Here's how your `Person` class would look with a copy constructor and (for completeness) a `Copy()` method:

```
public class Person
{
    private string _name;

    public Person() // Default constructor is required if there are any other constructors!
    {
        Name = "";
    }

    public Person(Person other) // Copy constructor.
    {
        this.Name = other.Name;
    }

    public Person Copy()
    {
        return new Person(this); // Use copy constructor to return a copy of this.
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public void Change()
    {
        Name = "F";
    }
}
```

You would then use this as follows, for your sample:

```
static void Main()
{
    Person person  = new Person();
    Person person2 = new Person();
    Person current = new Person();

    person.Name  = "John";
    person2.Name = "Doe";
    current.Name = "Robert";

    person  = new Person(current); // Using Copy Constructor.
    person2 = current.Copy();      // Using Copy() method.
    current.Change();  // Only changes current, not person or person2.
}
```

Note: I recommend that you don't implement the `Copy()` method and just stick to the copy-constructor unless (as noted previously) there is an inheritance hierarchy for your class. That would be [advanced usage beyond the scope of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119623/clone-derived-class-from-base-class-method)!